# Don't show confirmation popup when voting to delete a question if you already voted

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

When someone votes to delete a question that they have already voted for, a similar dialog appears:

[image]

Once confirmed, this appears:

[image]

Can the error message be shown directly instead of showing the confirmation box?

Comment: They already load the delete votes on the page so it should be doable, I would think

Comment: @Machavity As far as I can tell - that number is cached. It does seem as though fetching actual votes is costly (hence the delay when opening the flag and close dialogs). Only when the actual vote is cast does it check *who* has voted already, and return an error.